Reversing Axis Order in Line Charts with SlapKit.Excel
I'm struggling to find a way to reverse the order of axes in line charts. In Excel, there's an option to reverse the axis order for both the horizontal and vertical axes directly through the interface, but I can't find a similar functionality in SlapKit's documentation or API.
Has anyone managed to achieve this using SlapKit.Excel?
